# Laravel 5 push() not saving hasOne relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my destroy function of my controller, I'm attempting to take a copy of my object (model with one relationship) and insert it into another database before deleting it. However only the model is being created and not the relationship. Why is this happening?

Destroy function:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::with('Phone')->find($id);
        $archive = $user->replicate();
        $archive ->changeConnection('mysql2');
        $archive ->push();
   }
```

User model:

```
public function phone()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
   }
```

Phone model:

```
  public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
```

When I insert via the store function in my controller, it sets up the relationship just fine:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        // Validation has passed, insert data into database
       $user= User::create($request->all());
      $user->Phone()->create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Is `$user= User::create($request->all());` works for saving?

Comment: @Hiren Gohel - yes it's working for saving. I've got no issues with my store function. Just destroy function is only inserting Users and not Phone

Comment: May be there is issue of naming! you used `Phone` and you defined `phone` in your model.

Comment: Also, use `$archive->{attribute} = {value};` before `$archive ->push();` Let me know if this works!!

Comment: Is above solutions works for you??